# Laravel 5 пагинатор выводит всю коллекцию вместо одной страницы

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

У меня есть код выборки модели:

```
$list = $post->with(['actualBasicStats' => function($query){
        //for filters
    }])
        ->with(['actualExtStats' => function($query){
        //for filters
    }])
        ->whereIn('group_id', $groups->pluck('id'))
        ->paginate();
```

Если сделать dd() результата то получается вот такое:

[image: dd()]

Но при попытке вывести данные на фронт использую blade выводится вся коллекция за раз и строится пагинатор:

```
<tbody>
    {{--{{dd($list)}}--}}
    @foreach($list as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>{{str_limit($post->text, 100)}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualBasicStats->likes or 0}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualBasicStats->reposts or 0}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualBasicStats->comments or 0}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualExtStats->reach_total or 0}} / {{$post->actualExtStats->reach_subscribers or 0}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualExtStats->to_group or 0}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualExtStats->join_group or 0}}</td>
        <td>{{$post->actualExtStats->links or 0}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{{$list->render()}}
```

[image: Вывод на фронт]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в глобальном скоупе:

```
static::addGlobalScope('first300', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->limit(300);
    });
```

Он переопределяет лимит для выводимых постов на странице.
Решил проблему:

```
$list = $post->withoutGlobalScope('first300')->with(['actualBasicStats' => function($query){
        //for filters
    }])
        ->with(['actualExtStats' => function($query){
        //for filters
    }])
        ->whereIn('group_id', $groups->pluck('id'))
        ->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Введи в модели не `->paginate()` а `->paginate(15)` и получишь 15 записей на странице

Comment: Если не указано значение, то берется стандартное из модели (15), но да, я пробовал, не помогает.